# Bind jquery ui event to local function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I'm busy building a javascript class to automate the creation of Jquery UI Sliders.

```
    CustomSlider.prototype.initialize = function(slider_id, min_id, max_id, step, min, max){
        this.$slider = $('#' + slider_id);
        this.$min = $('#' + min_id);
        this.$max = $('#' + max_id);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.step = step;

        this.$slider.slider({
            range: true,
            step: this.step,
            min: this.min,
            max: this.max,
            values: [(this.min + (step * 4)), (this.max - (step * 4))],
            slide: this.slide(event, ui)
        });

        this.$min.text(this.min + (step * 4));
        this.$max.text(this.max - (step * 4));
    };

    CustomSlider.prototype.slide = function(event, ui){
        this.$min.text(ui.values[0]);
        this.$max.text(ui.values[1]);
    };
```

When I try to bind the slide event it won't take the "event" and "ui" variables.
How can I bind this event to my own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be just

```
    this.$slider.slider({
        range: true,
        step: this.step,
        min: this.min,
        max: this.max,
        values: [(this.min + (step * 4)), (this.max - (step * 4))],
        slide: this.slide
    });
```

You need to assign the function reference as the value for `slide` property.

In your case you are calling the `this.slide` function as assigns the value returned by it to the slide property, in this case undefined